# Is this Knot Theory statement True? If yes how can one prove it?

Tags: knot-theory

Let D be a knot diagram of a knot K (Assume D has more than 2 crossings). Then there is a crossing in the diagram D, such that the diagram obtained by changing this crossing can be simplified (via Reidemeister moves) into a diagram having 2 crossings less than D.

Comment: Is this a question you found somewhere, or is this a conjecture of yours? Do you have evidence that it might be true? It seems plausible, but it might be helpful knowing more about what you know.

Comment: @KyleMiller This is a conjecture of mine. I came up with it while trying to find unknotting numbers of a certain class of knots (Census Knots) by doing crossing changes. I noticed that every knot (or diagram of a knot) had this property, and if it would be true, One could get a general upper bound of the unknotting number of a knot based on the crossings of a diagram of it ( unknotting(K) =< (crossing_number_of_a_diagram_of_K).ceil()/2). I could imagine that there is some stronger statement out there from which it would follow. I Hope this helps.

Comment: The bound $u(K) \leq \lfloor c(K)/2\rfloor$ is known at least (as mentioned in [a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108312/problems-about-the-estimate-the-unknotting-number), if you can flip some number of crossings in a diagram to unknot it, you can also flip the complementary set of crossings). At least for the knots in KnotInfo, it seems like the bound is a strict $<$. (The free text criterion `crossing_number <= 2 * unknotting_number` on [advanced search](https://knotinfo.math.indiana.edu/index3.php) turns up no results.)

Comment: For your question, certainly if a minimal crossing diagram has a "bigon" (what should be known as a "digon," but that's what they're called in the literature) you can change one of the two crossings incident to it and perform a Reidemeister II move to remove two crossings. That leaves knots whose Conway notation has only the +1 and -1 tangles inserted into a fundamental polyhedron. I'm not sure how to deal with these yet.

Comment: Okay thanks, the statement in the mentioned comment was really useful.

Comment: Perhaps, this is a little late to the party, but equality is attained in $u(K)\leq \lfloor c(K)/2 \rfloor$ for the $(2,n)$ torus knots. I'm not aware of any other examples though.